# Detecting swiping out of the screen using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

On non-touch devices, `document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave')` would fire when moving the mouse out of the window. There's no corresponding touch event, but there's `pointerleave`. I expected this to fire only when moving your finger off the edge of the screen, but it's also firing when lifting your finger.

I also tried listening to `touchmove` and `pointermove` to detect when my finger is near the edge of the screen. However, the events will often stop firing before my finger gets close enough to the edge, the distance between `event.clientX` and the edge of the screen is often ~10px.

It seems like it's impossible to detect the difference between swiping from 10px from the edge to the edge and tapping 10px from the edge. Is there a consistent way to detect moving your finger off the edge of the screen?

Comment: out of curiosity, what do you expect this event *means*? Like what kind of action do you assume your user did for such an event to happen? What would they expect to happen that you want to implement?

Comment: I'm getting a bug where I'm trying to detect taps using touchstart/touchend for gestures, but if I accidentally slide my finger off the edge of the screen, it's registering as a tap